# Why doesn't my render look anything like my camera view?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, 3d-view

I am having trouble trying to figure out why my render isn't appearing like my camera view. All objects that need to be seen are checked on.

I would greatly appreciate any help whatsoever. I've attached a screenshot of my situation. The left is my render result, and the right is my camera view.

Thank you so so much!

[image: my render vs my camera view]

Comment: Looks like the volume is turned off for *viewport* rendering...?

Comment: Right the `Cube Volume` and `Cube Volume.001` are hidden in the viewport, but active in the render. You can deactivate them in the render by clicking on the camera icon in the outliner.

Comment: Do you have your lamp setting way too high?